# Rails App Excessive Disk Read/Write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, operations

a rails app that's been running in production for almost a year began excessive disk read/writes after a push we did today.

Here's a [read total graph](http://f.cl.ly/items/3X0k062P2i0p220Q1t2G/Image%202013.09.07%206%3A48%3A55%20PM.png).

As well as a [read ops graph](http://f.cl.ly/items/1Q2D2k0L0p3J3p213H10/Image%202013.09.07%207%3A00%3A01%20PM.png)

We pushed at around 22:30 and disk usage went bananas.

If I'm doing the calculations right, we're writing 476m of data every few minutes?

`500000000 / 1024 / 1024 = 476.83`

Either way, I'm unsure where to begin looking.  Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  The box went into swap.  AWS auto-scaled the boxes out and replaced with new ones.  <3 amazon.  :)